# type not defined in asp.net mvc js file

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

i am getting an error type not defined when i try to register the name space
in the js file

```
Type.registerNamespace("OrganizationStructure");
OrganizationStructure.OrgStructure = function() {
            this.orgStructureId = null; 
            this.name = null;
            this.nodeList = null; 

}
OrganizationStructure.OrgStructure.registerClass('OrganizationStructure.OrgStructure');

OrganizationStructure.Node = function() {
            this.parent = null;
            this.name = null;
            this.list = null;

        }
        OrganizationStructure.Node.registerClass('OrganizationStructure.Node');
```

i dont know why this error occuring

Answer (score 1):

`registerNamespace` and `registerClass` functions are part of the MS AJAX framework and have nothing to do with jquery. So the question is which one of the two frameworks you would like to use MS AJAX or jquery? So if you want to use those functions make sure you have included the proper files: `MicrosoftAjax.js`, `MicrosoftMvcAjax.js`.

Comment: so it is ms ajax but it did not solve my problem of getting the js errot type not defined

Comment: I think that this code requires you to use a server side scriptmanager control which is not supported in ASP.NET MVC. Not sure about it though. I have never seen someone using things like this in an ASP.NET MVC application when there's jquery.

Comment: yup this was my point since i need an script manager that is not possible in mvc so what is the way out for this can you suggest some thing

Comment: @ankur, well, you will have to modify this code so that it no longer relies on those functions. You could rewrite it to take benefit of jquery.

Comment: @Darin thanks a lot man i will explain you my scenario i have made  a tree with the help of jquery and little bit of js now i have to read the tree and prepare a json object to dump it to my controller how can i prepare the json object

Comment: @ankur, this will depend on what format that this tree expects the object to be in. But to define an object in javascript you could simply: `var obj = { id: 1, name: 'foo', complex: { id: 5, someOtherProp: 'some value' } };`

Comment: @Darin i will be using the nested set model to assign the left right value to the tree so the structure that i made in my two classes is being needed for me to prepare the json object